# How to use Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConiguration in my XUnit unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, xunit, xunit.net

In my Asp.net Core 2.0 application, I am trying to unit test my data service layer (.Net Standard Class Library) that uses the *Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration* dependency injection. 
I am using XUnit and don't know how to pass `IConfiguration` from my unit test class. I tried the following implementation and getting the error

> Message: The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: IConfiguration configuration.

I am really new to the testing frameworks and don't even know if dependency injection can be used as I am trying to do in my code snippet.

My Unit test class is as follow

```cs
public class SqlRestaurantDataCLUnitTest
{
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
    public SqlRestaurantDataCLUnitTest(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }
    [Fact]
    public void AddTest()
    {
        var restaurantDataCL = new SqlRestaurantDataCL(configuration);
        var restaurant = new Restaurant
        {
            Name = "TestName",
            Cuisine = CuisineType.None
        };

        var result = restaurantDataCL.Add(restaurant);

        Assert.IsNotType(null, result.Id);    
    }
}
```

My data service layer is as follow

```cs
public class SqlRestaurantDataCL : IRestaurantDataCL
{
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
    public SqlRestaurantDataCL(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }
    public Restaurant Add(Restaurant restaurant)
    {
        using (var db = GetConnection())
        {
            string insertSql = @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[RESTAURANTS]([Cuisine], [Name]) 
                                OUTPUT INSERTED.*
                                VALUES (@Cuisine, @Name)";

            restaurant = db.QuerySingle<Restaurant>(insertSql, new
            {
                Cuisine = restaurant.Cuisine,
                Name = restaurant.Name
            });

            return restaurant;
        }
    }

    private IDbConnection GetConnection()
    {
        return new SqlConnection(configuration.GetSection(Connection.Name).Value.ToString());
    }
}

public class Connection
{
    public static string Name
    {
        get { return "ConnectionStrings: OdeToFood"; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing around an `IConfiguration` object anyway? Shouldn't you have a nice POCO with all your settings as properties? Anyway, just make an object that implements `IConfiguration` and returns the settings appropriate for your test.

Comment: @David will you please explain with some code sample?

Comment: I would have to agree with DavidG on this one about the `IConfiguration` dependency. How is this dependency being used. Show `SqlRestaurantDataCL.GetConnection()`. This might end up being a design issue masked in an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Nkosi I have updated my question with the GetConnection() code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unit tests have a very useful habit of exposing design issues. In this case you have made some design choices that prove difficult to test because of tight coupling to framework concerns as well as static concerns.

First, it looks like `SqlRestaurantDataCL` actually depends on a connection factory

```cs
public interface IDbConnectionFactory {
    IDbConnection GetConnection();
}
```

Which would refactor the data implementation as advised to depend on that abstraction.

```cs
public class SqlRestaurantDataCL : IRestaurantDataCL {
    private readonly IDbConnectionFactory factory;

    public SqlRestaurantDataCL(IDbConnectionFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }
    public Restaurant Add(Restaurant restaurant) {
        using (var connection = factory.GetConnection()) {
            string insertSql = @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[RESTAURANTS]([Cuisine], [Name]) 
                                OUTPUT INSERTED.*
                                VALUES (@Cuisine, @Name)";

            restaurant = connection.QuerySingle<Restaurant>(insertSql, new {
                Cuisine = restaurant.Cuisine,
                Name = restaurant.Name
            });

            return restaurant;
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

The assumption is that Dapper is being used to make the query above.

With the introduction of the abstracted dependencies, they can be mocked as needed when testing in isolation.

```cs
public class SqlRestaurantDataCLUnitTest {

    [Fact]
    public void AddTest() {
        //Arrange
        var connection = new Mock<IDbConnection>();
        var factory = new Mock<IDbConnectionFactory>();
        factory.Setup(_ => _.GetConnection()).Returns(connection.Object);

        //...setup the connection to behave as expected

        var restaurantDataCL = new SqlRestaurantDataCL(factory.Object);
        var restaurant = new Restaurant {
            Name = "TestName",
            Cuisine = CuisineType.None
        };

        //Act
        var result = restaurantDataCL.Add(restaurant);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotType(null, result.Id);
    }
}
```

Now if you meant to actually touch the real database then this is not an isolation unit test but instead an integration test, that will have a different approach.

In production code, the factory can be implemented

```cs
public class SqlDbConnectionFactory : IDbConnectionFactory {
    private readonly ConnectionSetings connectionSettings;

    SqlDbConnectionFactory(ConnectionSetings connectionSettings) {
        this.connectionSettings = connectionSettings;
    }

    public IDbConnection GetConnection() {
        return new SqlConnection(connectionSettings.Name));
    }
}
```

Where `ConnectionSetings` is defined as a simple POCO to store the connection string

```cs
public class ConnectionSetings {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In the composition root the settings can be extracted from configurations

```cs
IConfiguration Configuration; //this would have been set previously

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    //...

    var settings = Configuration
        .GetSection("ConnectionStrings:OdeToFood")
        .Get<ConnectionSetings>();

    //...verify settings (if needed)

    services.AddSingleton(settings);
    services.AddSingleton<IDbConnectionFactory,SqlDbConnectionFactory>();
    services.AddSingleton<IRestaurantDataCL,SqlRestaurantDataCL>();
    //Note: while singleton was used above, You can decide to use another scope
    //      if so desired.
}
```

There was really no need to be passing `IConfiguration` around as it is more of a framework concern that is really only relevant at start up.

Comment: Your answer really helped me to understand the concept. Thanks!

Comment: It is complaining about the connection in factory.Setup(_=> _.GetConnection()).Returns(connection). It says, cannot convert from 'Moq.Mock<System.Data.IDbConnection>' to 'System.Data.IDbConnection'

Comment: @LearningCurve that was a typo. fixed.

Comment: can you please help me to setup the connection for the isolation test in the Arrange section. I have followed your example and getting the NullReferenceException when service layer (public Restaurant Add(Restaurant restaurant)) execute the insert statement. Apologies for any nuisance, I am really new to all this stuff.

Comment: @LearningCurve have a look at this article https://mikhail.io/2016/02/unit-testing-dapper-repositories/

Comment: @LearningCurve apparently dapper is a pain to unit test in isolation. found another library that might help https://github.com/half-ogre/dapper-wrapper

Comment: I been through few posts where ppl mentioned about the pain of isolation tests and that's why I was wondering if I should be doing them at all or if I really need to learn about it at this stage? Integration test sounds easy and I think I should focus on one thing at a time. Currently, I am completely bogged down with the isolation and the integration.

Comment: @LearningCurve For low level stuff like your data access example, integration tests should be enough but that is a matter of opinion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176331/discussion-between-learning-curve-and-nkosi).