# Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStringName").Get<?> always null

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.0, class-library, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

In my Asp.net Core 2.0 application, I am trying to implement the design of not to use the IConfiguration constructor dependency for connection strings in my class library project as advised by @Nkosi [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51403132/how-to-use-microsoft-extensions-configuration-iconiguration-in-my-xunit-unit-tes/51404119?noredirect=1#comment89814984_51404119).

In this approach it is unable to bind the configuration instance to the new instance of type as in the following lines of code

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
//...

var settings = Configuration
    .GetSection("ConnectionStrings:OdeToFood")
    .Get<ConnectionSetings>();

//...verify settings (if needed)

services.AddSingleton(settings);
}

public class ConnectionSetings
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I can see `Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:OdeToFood")` returning the "Key", "Path" and "Value" attributes but it fails to do the bindings and return null in settings.

I have seen similar questions where ppl have recommended solutions like as follow but none of them is working for me.

```
services.Configure<ConnectionsSetings>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:OdeToFood"));
```

Also,

```
Configuration
    .GetSection("ConnectionStrings:OdeToFood").Bind<>
```

Following is the appsettings.json

```
{
"Greeting": "Hello!!!",
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "OdeToFood": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=OdeToFood;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}
```

Following is the immediate window screen shot of Configuration.GetSection output where I can see Key, Path and Value

[image]

From the following screenshot it can be seen the setting variable is coming null

[image]

Comment: Are the settings coming from the appsettings.json file? If so, is this file configured as "Content" or as "Copy to Output Directory"?

Comment: Yes, it is appsetting.json file and configured as content

Comment: What is the structure of appsettings.json?

Comment: @LearningCurve Show us your app settings json file

Comment: Not at my pc but it is very basis with ConnectionStrings section that has OdeToFood connection string in it. Don’t forget, Configuration.Getsection can read the file and provide the value. It is the mapping to the ConnectionsSeting file that is not happening

Comment: @LearningCurve I was away from my machine when you asked earlier. Can you show a snippet of settings file with the section showing the connections. Should help with identifying the problem.

Comment: I have updated my original question with appsettings.json and screenshots @Nkosi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve with provided code, but in order to get value instead of null, you should have the following section in your appsettings.json:

```
{
  ...

  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "OdeToFood": {
      "Name": "someConncetionString"
    } 
  },

  ...
}
```

Then the following code will return the object:

```
var settings = Configuration
    .GetSection("ConnectionStrings:OdeToFood")
    .Get<ConnectionSetings>();
```

Comment: That’s exactly what I’m doing right now @Alex but settings coming up null.

Comment: @LearningCurve, so could you share your appsettings.json?

Comment: I have modified my question with appsettings.json and the error screenshot @Alex

Comment: @LearningCurve your json data lacks “Name”

Comment: Thank you very much Alex. Such a stupid mistake!. Couldn't try your proposed solution yesterday as my day was over. Thanks once again and courtesy to @NKosi who helped me to setup this design.