# XUnit mocked db connection dapper error, 'Object is not set to an instance of an object' when executing sql statement

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core-2.0, dapper, xunit, xunit.net

I am trying to unit test my service layer as advised by @NKosi [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51403132/how-to-use-microsoft-extensions-configuration-iconiguration-in-my-xunit-unit-tes). I am able to do the integration test successfully by implementing the actual factory implementation without mocking anything but can't do the unit test (by mocking IDbConnection and my SQL connection factory class) as Dapper query executing fails with the error 'Object not set to an instance of an object'.

My IDbConnection factory and its implementation is as follow

```
public interface IDbConnectionFactory
{
    IDbConnection CreateConnection();
}

public class ConnectionSetings
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SqlConnectionFactory : IDbConnectionFactory
{
    private readonly ConnectionSetings connectionSettings;

    public SqlConnectionFactory(ConnectionSetings connectionSettings)
    {
        this.connectionSettings = connectionSettings;
    }
    public IDbConnection CreateConnection()
    {
        return new SqlConnection(connectionSettings.Name);
    }
}
```

And the XUnit test is as follow

```
    [Fact]
    public void Get_RestaurantById_ReturnsRestaurant()
    {
        //Arrange
        var connection = new Mock<IDbConnection>();
        var dbConnectionFactory = new Mock<IDbConnectionFactory>();
        dbConnectionFactory.Setup(x => x.CreateConnection()).Returns(connection.Object);

        //Act
        var result = new SqlRestaurantDataCL(dbConnectionFactory.Object).Get(1);

        //Assert
        result.Name.Equals("Test Name 1");
        //Assert.Equal("Test Name 1", result.Name);
    }
```

And the Service Layer is as follow

```
public class SqlRestaurantDataCL : IRestaurantDataCL
{
    private readonly IDbConnectionFactory factory;
    public SqlRestaurantDataCL(IDbConnectionFactory factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public Restaurant Get(int id)
    {
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        {
            var selectSql = @"SELECT * From Restaurants Where Id = @Id";

            var restaurant = connection.QuerySingleOrDefault<Restaurant>(selectSql, new
            {
                id
            });

            return restaurant;
        }
    }
}
```

Following is the error screenshot

[image]

Comment: The problem here is that the amount of mocking needed to setup the mock connection to safely navigate the `QuerySingleOrDefault` Dapper extension is not worth the headache in my opinion. That is a major issue with trying to mock code you do not own or control like 3rd party dependencies, which in this case is Dapper

Comment: I personally would have added another layer of abstraction between my code and that extension to work around the coupling.

Comment: you mean some sort of business logic layer that will instantiate the db connection and call the data service layer so that I can get through the dapper barrier by mocking the business logic layer?

Comment: no basically a wrapper for the dapper extensions that would allow you to mock behavior without all the knock on effects

Comment: But personally I would not have unit tested `SqlRestaurantDataCL` as I see it as one of the lowest levels that interact directly with the data source. I would have focused on what depended on `IRestaurantDataCL` and mock it for those tests

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @NKosi. I successfully created the integration test on my data access layer with your help but I am also eager to learn about the unit testing. Although, I completely agree that unit testing is unnecessary at such low level. Anyways, I have got it working by implementing the 'Mikhail' solution https://mikhail.io/2016/02/unit-testing-dapper-repositories/ that was also suggested by yourself in my other stack over flow post (referred in my question ). I will post my answer later if anyone else need it.

Comment: Perfect. technically that is still an integration test but they had to do that route to get around the troubles with mocking Dapper correctly. Once you are satisfied with how it is working, then that is great.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you on that note and also mentioned by @Mikhail himself. I think it is something that is quite close to the Unit testing and surely has some value .

Comment: Now do not let this experience with dapper dissuade you on unit testing. This is just one of those rare edge cases. Unit testing on a while not normally this troublesome. In fact this one exposes what can happen when you couple to uncontrollable code. Unit tests have a knack for exposing troublesome code.

Answer (score 1):

Following is the answer to my question if anyone is in similar situation. Before following this solution, I would suggest to read @NKosi comments above and consult @Mikhail's solution [Here](https://mikhail.io/2016/02/unit-testing-dapper-repositories/).

> ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite package added to use in memory appraoch

```
internal class InMemoryDatabase
{
    private readonly OrmLiteConnectionFactory dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(":memory:", SqliteDialect.Provider);

    public IDbConnection OpenConnection() => this.dbFactory.OpenDbConnection();

    public void Insert<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        using (var db = this.OpenConnection())
        {
            db.CreateTableIfNotExists<T>();
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                db.Insert(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Data Access layer is as follow

```
    public IEnumerable<Restaurant> GetAll()
    {
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        {
            //return connection.Query<Restaurant>("Select * From [dbo].[Restaurants] Order By Name");
            return connection.Query<Restaurant>("Select * From Restaurant Order By Name");
        }
    }
```

Unit test is as follow

```
    [Fact]
    public void Get_RestaurantById_ReturnsRestaurant()
    {
        //Arrange
        var restaurants = new List<Restaurant>
        {
            new Restaurant { Id = 1, Name = "Test Name 1", Cuisine = CuisineType.None},
            new Restaurant { Id = 2, Name = "Test Name 2", Cuisine = CuisineType.French},
            new Restaurant { Id = 3, Name = "Test Name 3", Cuisine = CuisineType.German},
            new Restaurant { Id = 4, Name = "Test Name 4", Cuisine = CuisineType.Italian},
            new Restaurant { Id = 5, Name = "Test Name 5", Cuisine = CuisineType.None}
        };

        var db = new InMemoryDatabase();
        db.Insert(restaurants);

        var connection = new Mock<IDbConnection>();
        var dbConnectionFactoryMock = new Mock<IDbConnectionFactory>();
        dbConnectionFactoryMock.Setup(c => c.CreateConnection()).Returns(db.OpenConnection());

        //Act
        var result = new SqlRestaurantDataCL(dbConnectionFactoryMock.Object).GetAll();

        //Assert            
        result.Should().BeEquivalentTo(restaurants);

    }
```